# draw circles on every span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I want to draw circles on chars that i gave a span element. I already got it working with one element (see commented code). I only want to do it by every span element.
To start with i first tried to do it with a hover but i already failed at that. Instand of a hover it just should happen when the function draw get's called.

```
function draw() {  
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(plotX1, 0);

    $("p").find("span").hover(function(){

            console.log("hover");
            var x = $(this).offsetLeft;
            var y = $(this).offsetTop;
            y += $(this).offsetHeight;
            ellipse(ctx, x, y, 10);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 50)";
            ctx.stroke();   
    });


    ctx.restore();

    /*
// this worked on the element with id s2
    var x = s2.offsetLeft;
    var y = s2.offsetTop;
    y += s2.offsetHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 250, 0)";
    //ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    ellipse(ctx, x, y, 10);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 50)";
    ctx.stroke();
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/eEVJU/)**

this is at least closer to what you were looking for, the hover's work, it draws the circles, but it also connects the circles, should be able to easily fix that (maybe with `ctx.moveTo()`)

```
function draw() {
    $('#canv').attr('width', $('p').width()).attr('height', $('p').height());

    //ctx.translate(plotX1, 0);
    $('p span').hover(function() {
        ctx.save();

        var x = this.offsetLeft,
            y = this.offsetTop;
        y += this.offsetHeight / 2;

        //ctx.moveTo(x, y);

        ellipse(ctx, x, y, 10);

        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 50)";
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();
    }, function() {
        clearCanvas(ctx);
    });
}
```

I think the main issue may have been where you were using `$(this).offsetLeft;` to get offsets (where `$(this)` is a jQuery object).  `this.offsetLeft` worked.

---

*After thought:*

Not sure what your end goal is but you could also do a simple `box-shadow` around the span's with CSS

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/cwL2Q/)

```
p span:hover {box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #f00;border-radius:10px;}
```

Comment: with your piece of code i see nothing. Maybe because the canvas is over the whole page (i also can't select text). That the canvas is over the whole page must stay that way.

what is this line for?
$('#canv').attr('width', $('p').width()).attr('height', $('p').height());

Comment: `$('#canv').attr('width', $('p').width()).attr('height', $('p').height());` sets the canvas size to the same size as the paragraph.  I'm not seeing what you're seeing, using Chrome the circles show up and I can select the text.  Getting different results in Firefox, can select text but only one circle shows on the spans when I hover over them.

Comment: I logged x and y to console, x is undefined and y is nan.